# Firebase App SMS doesn’t show correct App Name

Tags: firebase

While using signInWithPhone, firebase sends an SMS in the format of “123456 is your verification code for %APP NAME%”

However, App Name is instead showing as my firebase url, which is something like app.firebaseapp.io

I read in answers to similar questions that after you publish, firebase gets the correct app name from the App Store. My app is published, but still shows the firebase app url.

What is wrong here? Is there a configuration option I need to change? Is there something in firebase console I can edit?

Answer (score 0):

Check Firebase **Project Settings => General => Public Facing Name** on Firebase Console.

[image]